# iterate rows of a column and remove all text after specific words in python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in python to remove all text if a specific combination of words is found in a row?
I have six different combinations of words after which the text should be deleted ('from the manufacturer' is an example). I want to iterate over rows of a column and remove all the text found after these words.

```
list_of_words = ['Descrizione Prodotto', 'Produktbeschreibung des Herstellers', 'Description du fabricant', 'From the manufacturer', 'Descripción Prodotto']
var = df['info']
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for word in list_of_words:
        if word in var:
            var.split(word, 1)[0]
```

Comment: What do you mean by removing all the text? Do you want to clear the data frame?

Comment: Only the text that's present after the words from the list_of_words, including the words as 'Descrizione Prodotto'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, using a lambda function:

```
list_of_words = ['Descrizione Prodotto', 'Produktbeschreibung des Herstellers', 'Description du fabricant', 'From the manufacturer', 'Descripción Prodotto']

def clear(x):
    for i in list_of_words:
        if i in x:
            x=x[:x.find(i)+len(i)]
    return x

df['info']=df['info'].apply(lambda x: clear(x))
```

Comment: thank you, that worked.Combined with the suggestion from Serge de Gosson de Varennes it removes the words from the list also. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! If you want to remove the word as well,just replace this in function: `x=x[:x.find(i)+len(i)]`  by this  `x=x[:x.find(i)]`